# Delete Query Issue in MySQL and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, delete, phpmyadmin

I am facing a strange issue with MySQl. I am using PHP and MySQL to built an app. When I am trying to delete records from the table it runs successfully but no record is deleted from the database.

Below I am attaching screenshot for reference.

```
DELETE FROM `Invoice`
WHERE `InvoiceNo` IN ('20092,20091,20090,20314,20404,20403,20402,20401,20400,20399,20398,20397,20396,20395,20394,20393,20392,20391,20390,20389,20388,20387,20386,20385,20384,20383,20382,20381,20380,20379,20378,20377,20376,20375,20374,20373,20372,20371,20370,20369,20368,20367,20366,20365,20364,20363,20362,20361,20360,20359,20358,20357,20356,20355,20354,20353,20352,20351,20350,20349,20348,20347,20346,20345,20344,20343,20342,20341,20340,20339,20338,20337,20336,20335,20334)
```

**Delete Query Screenshot**
[image]

Then I run select query and found that all records are there inplace.

**Select Query Screenshot**
[image]

It is strange for me. I am unable to find out the issue. Is there any mistake in my query?

Comment: Post the actual code of the `DELETE` statement, not images. Seems you have some quotes inside the `IN`, causing no row to match the WHERE and no row to be deleted.

Comment: I added the delete query

Comment: This is not a valid query. There is a quote, just after the parenthesis, `IN ('20092, ...)`, but no ending quote. You probably had an ending quote as well somewhere. Remove both of them and the issue will be solved.

Comment: Why do you need quotes anyway? Is the `InvoiceNo` an integer or a varchar?

Comment: The posted query probably won't run, I don't see a closing quotation mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for your effort.

I found the solution.
CodeIgniter where_in() added single quotation automatically, which is a bug in codeigniter. I use where() in place of where_in(). Issue fixed.

Comment: I seriously doubt that CodeIgniter has such a bug. What version are you using? Where is this bug documented? Show us the CI code.

Comment: I am using CI 2.X, $this->db->where_in('InvoiceNo',$invoice_ids);
$this->db->delete('Invoice');